# Google Maps infowindow callout is a few pixels out

Tags: maps, infowindow, callout

it's my first time post at stackoverflow. (A bit nervous)

I'm having an issue around the infowindow callout box for Google Maps as shown on the image here:  [Infowindow callout](http://imgur.com/TnY2scU)

There's about 2-3 pixels of the callout pointer sticking out from the bottom of the infobox.

I did have a problem with the rendering before and that was already solved by applying "max-width:none" to the map div. Haven't changed anything else.

It would be awesome if I could get some help solving this issue... Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of old, but I was running into the same issue and since there isn't an answer I will post my fix.

In my CSS I am resetting the box-sizing property on all elements

```
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

In order to fix this I applied a class to the `div` that wrapped the Google Map and set the box-sizing property back to the `initial` state.

```
.google-maps * { -moz-box-sizing: initial; -webkit-box-sizing: initial; box-sizing: initial; }
```